# How to compare local vim plugin version with github

Tags: vim, github

I use pathogen for plugin management, many plugin author does not show the version of the software specifically, therefore I copy and overwrite all my plugin from GitHub from time to time, I've installed git environment in my computer, is there any command can check local software version from GitHub and update by itself?

Comment: You mean check the local version of the software? That all depends on if the author actually gave it a version. You'll have to check which commit you have locally and compare that with the GitHub version which would be the most up-to-date.

Comment: Use Vim.org instead: you get changelogs and versions.

Comment: But a lot of author stop post the plugin on Vim.org

Comment: They are wrong and that practice shouldn't be encouraged: no changelog, downloading a specific release is hard at best… github is cool for building a community around your work but very bad for distributing that work to end users. Vim.org is not sexy but it does a much better job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have git installed then it's as simple as

Here, I'm using nerdtree as an example:

```
$ cd .vim/bundle/nerdtree
$ git pull
$ cd .vim/bundle/some-nifty-plugin-on-github-or-similar
```

I have a simple bash-script that does the above for the plugins that I use. Updating all is as simple as running `.vim/bundle/update.sh`

To check, the *version*, cd to that folder and do a:

```
$ git log    # displays the complete commit-log
$ git log -1 # the latest commit message
```

Hope I understood you correctly...

Comment: I would highly recommend using git submodules, then updating is a one-liner: 'git submodule foreach git pull'

Comment: @吳承諺 -- Don't be afraid to accept my answer if you liked it (green thingie next to the voting arraows on the left) :-)

Comment: @Max - no idea why I haven't been using submodules. I think I'll change noow :-)

Answer (score 0):

You want Vundle: https://github.com/gmarik/vundle

Vundle will work with the same plugin layout that Pathogen uses and will also install plugins under `~/.vim/bundle/`, but it will manage the Git cloning and updating for you. You can simply list a plugin as a `Bundle` in your `~/.vimrc` and run `:BundleInstall` to install it.

Using Vundle, you can run `:BundleInstall!` to update installed plugins to the latest version.

See also: Tim Lai’s blog post [“Moving Up: Upgrading From Pathogen to Vundle”](http://jameslaicreative.com/moving-up-upgrading-from-pathogen-to-vundle/).